# Interoperability problem between Visio 2016 or PowerPoint 365) ==> can't insert or embed and then edit Visio objects in PowerPoint 365

Tags: office365, powerpoint, visio

I have a problem with Visio 2016 and PowerPoint 365. I need to interoperate between Visio 2016 and PowerPoint 365, i.e., round-trip editing of embedded Visio 2016 diagrams in PowerPoint 365.

There is no "Paste Special..." menu and all pasted drawings from Visio always paste as picture or image, not an editable object.

I am using :

Microsoft® Visio® 2016 MSO (16.0.14228.20216) 64-bit Microsoft® PowerPoint® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14228.20216) 64-bit

WHAT I TRIED:

Converting to .VSD or .VSDX format, as some have suggested does not work.

I tried converting it in draw.io file from Visio to a diagrams.net and draw.io format, but that does not work.

I added the Developer's Menu in the Advanced Ribbon, but still no "Paste Special..." menu anywhere. Even though "Paste Special..." shows up on the Developers menu in the Ribbon configuration, it does not appear when the Visio object is on the PowerPoint Clipboard.

MY RESULTS:

PowerPoint Clipboard does not recognize the Visio object as an OLE editable Visio object.

I cannot copy and paste either Visio .VSD or .VSDX files as an editable object.  Everything is converted into a JPG or other image file type.

The "Paste Special..." menu is not available anywhere on the Ribbon or right-click menu.

It is ironic that I can paste diagrams in draw.io, and Enterprise Architect objects in native format, but not Microsoft's own Visio.vsdx or Visio.vsd file.

This is Microsoft's way of blocking people from trying to continue to work offline without Microsoft 365... "Let's make it as difficult as possible for people to stay off the cloud by killing interoperability between Office versions and causing incompatibility between offline and and online Office 365."    Thank you Microsoft for wasting our time again!! Office 98 to Office 2000 caused millions of people millions of lost hours with no backward compatibility between MS-Word.doc and MS-Word.docx files. What a hassle!

Does anyone know how to fix this interoperability issue?

Is there a registry setting or some other configuration change that can be made to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Insert>Object>Microsoft Visio Drawing and paste your Visio drawing there.